# Odd results on base64 operations

Tags: linux, zsh, base64

I am having weird output on base64 operations. I have something I want to programmatically download, and found that the links contains base64 encoded data (`{date}.zip`. This is evidenced by the following:

```bsh
> echo "MjAyMS0wMS0xMy56aXA="  | base64 --decode
2021-01-13.zip%
```

If I pipe that back into `base64`, I get the same result back:

```bsh
> echo "MjAyMS0wMS0xMy56aXA="  | base64 --decode | base64
MjAyMS0wMS0xMy56aXA=
```

However, if I pass the decoded string directly to base64, I get a different result:

```bsh
> echo "2021-01-13.zip"  | base64
MjAyMS0wMS0xMy56aXAK
```

Curious as to why this is happening, and how I can resolve.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `%` really there?

Comment: It is. I was going to add a P.S. on my question to get some insight into why, but neglected to do so. Might you know why?

Comment: Probably you're using `zsh`. It informs you this way there is no newline character at the end of the output. Other shells would not care, they would straightforwardly print their prompt. In effect the prompt would be in the same line, concatenated with `2021-01-13.zip`.

Comment: Yep - that's right. Tested this by dropping into a bash shell and what you thought is what manifested. Good to know!

Comment: So your tag should be `zsh` instead of `bash`, shouldn't it?

Comment: You're correct. Oversight on my end. Thanks, I'll modify it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Compare the output of these two commands:

```
echo "MjAyMS0wMS0xMy56aXA="  | base64 --decode | od -c
echo "2021-01-13.zip" | od -c
```

You will see there is no newline character in what `base64 --decode` prints (because the string you start with apparently does not encode a newline character). There is a newline character in what `echo` prints (because this is how `echo` works). Now try this:

```
echo -n "2021-01-13.zip"  | base64
```

Or [better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618):

```
printf '%s' "2021-01-13.zip"  | base64
```

Answer (score 27):

Echo adds by default a trailing end of line character.

Try without adding the end of line:

```
> echo -n "2021-01-13.zip"  | base64
MjAyMS0wMS0xMy56aXA=
```